# Очень странная ситуация

Tags: html, css

Верстал страничку, попал в непонятную ситуацию. В элементе

```
<div class="lowercontent">
    <div class="brandline">
        <span>brand brand brand brand brand brand</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Происходят очень странные вещи. Фон первого слова окрашивается в зеленоватый, второго и остальных в желтоватый цвет. Цвет текста остается черным, при том что в стилях задан другой цвет, и стили работают(не зачеркнуты). Ситуация возникает только в браузере opera. После глобальной перезагрузки страницы с удалением кэшированых файлов(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>) на секунду проблема пропадает, и затем появляется снова. В коде таких цветов не использовал, на всякий случай взял цвета пипеткой, попытался найти через <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> в коде, там их тоже нет(!?) В браузере chrome такого не происходит. С чем это может быть связано?
  "Что это может быть?"

[image: Что это может быть?]

---

Решил дописать строчку до конца, не влезло одно слово. Решил до решения проблемы написать слово не полностью, при bran все стили сработали. Т.е. нельзя использовать слово brand в opera?

Comment: Очень странные вещи. Названия блоков которые я раньше не использовал, цвета которые я раньше не использовал, пк залагал так как раньше никогда не лагал, пришлось перезагрузить и все пропало, как на хостинге так и на локальном диске... Остался только скриншот на память

Comment: >пришлось перезагрузить и все пропало, как на хостинге так и на локальном диске...

Восхитительная история. Это проделки ФСБ.

Answer (score 2):

На скриншоте видно, что используется *поиск по странице*

Как видно - ищется слово `brand`

Одно слово *brand* выделено, как текущее найденное, остальные - подсвечены как найдены.

Если выйти из режима поиска - цвета вернутся